# PHP imagettftext() center text

Tags: php, imagettftext

I want to center the text I add to my image using :

```
imagettftext($image, 85, 0, 250, 350, $color, $font, $txt );
```

I tried something like this :

```
$fontwidth1 = imagefontwidth($font);
$center1 = (imagesx($image)/2) - ($fontwidth1*(strlen($txt)/2));
```

However unfortunately it's not working.
The imagefontwidth($font) part does not work :(

Anyone has faced this issue before and know an solution / alternative method ?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not work"?  What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: (imagesx($image)/2) works gives correct value. ($fontwidth1*(strlen($txt)/2)) Returns 0.

Comment: And yes i set all other variables properly.

Comment: I suggest using [imagettfbbox()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php)

Comment: Thanks Austing, great hint. How can I add this answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `imagefontwidth` works best with fixed-width fonts. Like Austin Brunkhorst said, the most reliable way to get centered text uses `imagettfbbox`, like so:

```
$bbox = imagettfbbox(85, 0, $font, $txt);
$center1 = (imagesx($image) / 2) - (($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]) / 2);
```